# Removing a line containing a string in two columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited file:

```
TRINITY_DN42298_c0_g1_i1.p1 NA  NA
TRINITY_DN12995_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF06799 NA
TRINITY_DN2326_c0_g1_i4.p3  NA  NA
TRINITY_DN6047_c0_g1_i1.p1  PF10585 GO:0008641
TRINITY_DN37780_c0_g1_i3.p2 PF00071 GO:0003924,GO:0005525
TRINITY_DN2787_c0_g1_i2.p1  NA  NA
TRINITY_DN29879_c0_g1_i3.p1 PF01657 NA
TRINITY_DN72702_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00498 GO:0005515
TRINITY_DN24890_c0_g1_i7.p1 PF00854 GO:0016020,GO:0022857,GO:0055085
TRINITY_DN46477_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00069 GO:0004672,GO:0005524,GO:0006468
```

I want to remove lines having NA in both column 2 and 3:

```
TRINITY_DN12995_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF06799 NA
TRINITY_DN6047_c0_g1_i1.p1  PF10585 GO:0008641
TRINITY_DN37780_c0_g1_i3.p2 PF00071 GO:0003924,GO:0005525
TRINITY_DN29879_c0_g1_i3.p1 PF01657 NA
TRINITY_DN72702_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00498 GO:0005515
TRINITY_DN24890_c0_g1_i7.p1 PF00854 GO:0016020,GO:0022857,GO:0055085
TRINITY_DN46477_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00069 GO:0004672,GO:0005524,GO:0006468
```

Tried

```
sed -i '/NA/d' ./file.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '!($2 == "NA" && $3 == "NA")' file
```

The option `-F` sets the field separator to `\t` allowing to grab the 2nd and 3rd parameter and check if both their content is not `NA`. In such case `awk` prints the line.

Comment: You don't need the Field separator to be tab with his test data it worked fine for me without it. (Code golfed: `awk '$2$3!="NANA"'`)

Comment: @A.Danischewski The `-F` option is set because OP explicitly said: _I have a *tab delimited* file_

Comment: @A.Danischewski `$2$3!="NANA"` would fail when $2 is `NAN` and $3 is `A`, for example. You could do `'($2 FS $3) != ("NA" FS "NA")'` I suppose.

Comment: @EdMorton If you have to worry about it you should just check them individually. But if you wanted you could use the FS, since that's already "safe" in the sense that its already being utilized in delimiting fields. (E.g. if FS is a space: `awk '$2FS$3!=NA NA'`)

Comment: @A.Danischewski IMHO you always have to worry about it. That comparison you suggested would check if `$2FS$3` matched the contents of the variable named `NA` concatenated with itself (or it might do something else depending on the precedence of concatenation vs comparison - I wouldn't write code that relies on that precedence for clarity if nothing else). See [my previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539308/removing-a-line-containing-a-string-in-two-columns/539309?noredirect=1#comment1000723_539309) for how to compare the concatenation of $2 and $3 with a string.

Comment: @EdMorton It should have read "NA NA" on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Your script also deletes lines with just one `NA`, so simply add another one, separated by your delimiter (whitespace? tab? Let's say `[[:space:]]*`) and fix it to the end of the line with `$` to make it fields 2 and 3:

```
sed -i '/NA[[:space:]]*NA$/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways as shown:

```
$ grep -vP '^(?:(?!\t).)+\tNA\tNA(?=\t|$)' inp.tsv

$ sed -Ee 'h;s/\t/\n/;s/$/\t/;/\n(NA\t)\1/d;g' inp.tsv

$ perl -F'\t' -lane 'print if 2 != grep { /^NA$/ } @F[1,2]' inp.tsv

$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=any -F'\t' -lane 'print if any { ! /^NA$/ } @F[1,2]' inp.tsv

   # fs => field separator set to a TAB
   # nT => not TAB
   # F  => consecutive run of non TABs, a field
$ fs="`echo x | tr x '\011'`"; nT="[^${fs}]"; F="$nT$nT*"
$ sed -e "/^$F${fs}NA${fs}NA\$/d" -e "/^$F${fs}NA${fs}NA${fs}/d";exit
```

**Results:**

```
TRINITY_DN12995_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF06799 NA
TRINITY_DN6047_c0_g1_i1.p1  PF10585 GO:0008641
TRINITY_DN37780_c0_g1_i3.p2 PF00071 GO:0003924,GO:0005525
TRINITY_DN29879_c0_g1_i3.p1 PF01657 NA
TRINITY_DN72702_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00498 GO:0005515
TRINITY_DN24890_c0_g1_i7.p1 PF00854 GO:0016020,GO:0022857,GO:0055085
TRINITY_DN46477_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00069 GO:0004672,GO:0005524,GO:0006468
```

**Assumptions:**

- No leading TABs
- Unix style line endings => newline character = `\012`
- Locale set to LC_ALL=T
- Input file is readable by the user
- `grep` version supports `-P` option
- `sed` supports non-POSIX constructs like `\t`, `\n` on RHS, `(...)`
- Running on a `bash|sh` commandline

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command and worked fine

command

```
awk '$2 != "NA" && $3 != "NA" {print $0}'  filename
```

output

```
TRINITY_DN6047_c0_g1_i1.p1  PF10585 GO:0008641
TRINITY_DN37780_c0_g1_i3.p2 PF00071 GO:0003924,GO:0005525
TRINITY_DN72702_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00498 GO:0005515
TRINITY_DN24890_c0_g1_i7.p1 PF00854 GO:0016020,GO:0022857,GO:0055085
TRINITY_DN46477_c0_g1_i1.p1 PF00069 GO:0004672,GO:0005524,GO:0006468
```

Comment: It shud rather be: `awk '$2 != "NA" || $3 != "NA"'` coz we need to print even if one is non NA, IOW, not print when both are NA